# JavaScript(jQuery) event trigger ctrl+right arrow button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im need imitate press combination buttons  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
How i can after page load run trigger which
will be combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
im find this code

```
$("input").focus();
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 75; // # Some key code value
$("input").val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
$("input").trigger(e);
```

but i dont understand how i can insted

```
e.which = 75; // # Some key code value
```

write

```
e.which = ctrl code + right arrow code; // # Some key code value
```

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. You want to do X, you think Y (sending Ctrl+RighArrow to the input) will do it, so you've asked how to do Y. You'd probably be better off asking how to do X. (As a separate question; *this* question has already been scoped.)

Answer (score 1):

The keycode for right-arrow is 39; you can easily determine that by hooking it and looking at what value you get for `which` for a real event.

To indicate that the Ctrl key is down, you set `ctrlKey` to `true` on the event.

After focussing the input, you probably want to do the `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick to give the browser a chance to actually do that.

So:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $("input").focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 39; // 39 = right-arrow
        e.ctrlKey = true;
        $("input").trigger(e);
    }, 0);
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="one two three">
```

That said, it doesn't actually perform the action on Chrome and I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't on other browsers as well.

Comment: im try
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 39; // 39 = right-arrow
        e.ctrlKey = true;
        $("body").trigger(e);

Comment: @ИванСеменов See the last paragraph of the answer, and the comment on the question.

Comment: ok. how i can imitate press combination buttons ctrl+right arrow?its possible?